# Give visible blocks same height + also when resizing

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have an archive page with all prizes, sorted in different categories. Only one category is visible and by using the subnav, you can navigate through the categories. The blocks of the category that is visible all get the height of the largest visible block, but it doesn't work when the page is getting resized.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    function resizeElements() {
var highestBox = 0;
    $('.prijs__wrapper.active .item__cat .item__content').each(function(){  
        if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
            highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    });    
    $('.prijs__wrapper.active .item__cat .item__content').height(highestBox);
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    var $prijzenArchief = !!$('.post-type-archive-prijzen')[0];
    if ($prijzenArchief) {
        $('.prijzen__filter ul li:first').addClass('active');
        var tid = $(this).data('type-trigger');
        var $current = $('.prijzen__items .prijs__wrapper[data-type="' + tid + '"]').addClass('active');
            $('.prijzen__items .prijs__wrapper').not($current).removeClass('active');


        $('.prijzen__filter ul .filter-item').click(function() {
            $('.prijzen__filter ul .filter-item').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var tid = $(this).data('type-trigger');
            var $current = $('.prijzen__items .prijs__wrapper[data-type="' + tid + '"]').addClass('active');
            $('.prijzen__items .prijs__wrapper').not($current).removeClass('active');

            resizeElements();

        })

        $('.prijzen__filter ul .filter-item.active').trigger('click');

        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeElements);
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Wrap that code that resizes the elements in a function e.g. `resizeElements()`, then call that function after DOM is loaded, and attach it to the resize event of the window like so `window.addEventListener('resize', resizeElements);`

Comment: Where exactly should I implement it? I updates my full code

Comment: **#1** `jQuery(function ($) {` is basically the same as `$(document).ready(function () {
`. dont wrap them into each other only use either the first or the latter. Then your structure should be *1* function declarations (the new function and the resize code within), then your `$(document).ready(function () {` with a call to that new function within and the above mentioned handler for your window resize event. [here a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucpkexzv/)

Comment: I updated my code, but it still doesn't work. I get '$ is not a function'

Comment: Thats typically the case if you did not implement jQuery or implement it after you use it. check the order in which you add your JS files, jquery has to be first

Comment: BTW now you add `window.addEventListener('resize', resizeElements);` within a click event, everytime you click the `.prijzen__filter ul .filter-item` element you add a new event handler for the resize event. move that out of the click handler and directly into your `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: I use Wordpress so I didn't implement jQuery into my theme. I updates my code again, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can't seem to figure it out myself

Comment: did you enqueue the js file yourself? did you make jQuery a dependency?

Comment: I have this line in my functions.php: wp_enqueue_script( 'js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.6.0', true );